# Backoffice Hybris : How to assign an action (beforeSave) to a Product in editorArea

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

i am new in this so maybe you can help me.
I have to assign an action to a Product in editorArea **beforeSave**.I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to be a little more specific in what you are trying to do and what you have tried already. Please read the [tips on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will help you get a good answer sooner. A good tip is to add some code so that we can see what you are trying to do and what the problems might be, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to create an Hybris Interceptor. Basically, you should create your custom extension where all your specific logic will go. Then, simply define a Spring Bean extending the `PrepareInterceptor` which is called before it is saved to the database. If the idea is to run some validation on the data, Hybris proposes a `ValidateInterceptor` to achieve this.

```
public interface ValidateInterceptor extends Interceptor
{
    void onValidate(Object model, InterceptorContext ctx) throws InterceptorException;
}
```

See [Hybris documentation](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8bfbf43e8669101480d0f060d79b1baa.html) for a complete documentation about the Hybris interceptor logic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to validate Product attributes before are saved on the database. I have already my custom extension. Can you tell me how should it look the spring bean which is called before save? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Everything is detailed in the link I provided. I updated the interface in my answer, but I strongly encourage you to read that documentation page where it is explained in details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I start something and think i am on the good road . Kann you look please, if my beans are correct?                                                                                      `<bean id="ccProductLookupValidateInterceptor" class="com.cancom.core.productlookup.CCProductLookupValidateInterceptor"/>
 
 
 <bean id="MyValidateInterceptorMapping"  class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorMapping">
  <property name="interceptor" ref="ccProductLookupValidation"/>
  <property name="typeCode" value="Product"/>
 </bean>`

Comment: Yes, that's almost correct. The ref in your interceptorMapping should just contain the id of your interceptor, so in this case it would look like :
`<bean id="MyValidateInterceptorMapping" class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorMapping"> <property name="interceptor" ref="ccProductLookupValidateInterceptor"/> <property name="typeCode" value="Product"/> </bean>`

Comment: Hey @RomainVDK Could you please confirm that suppose an exception is thrown from validate interceptor , is there a way to display a message on backoffice, telling the user that this data should be like that ?